# Multiple versions of python and tkinter module

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I use 3 versions of python on Linux mint 18.3

```
silvock@silvock-TM1701 ~ $ python -V
Python 2.7.12
silvock@silvock-TM1701 ~ $ python3 -V
Python 3.5.2
silvock@silvock-TM1701 ~ $ python3.6 -V
Python 3.6.5
```

I'm able to import Tkinter with python2.7 and tkinter python3.6...

```
silvock@silvock-TM1701 ~ $ python 
Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import Tkinter
>>> 


silvock@silvock-TM1701 ~ $ python3.6
Python 3.6.5 (default, May  3 2018, 10:08:28) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tkinter
>>>
```

... but with python3 (python 3.5) it doesn't work.

```
silvock@silvock-TM1701 ~ $ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tkinter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    import _tkinter
ImportError: No module named '_tkinter'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    raise ImportError(str(msg) + ', please install the python3-tk package')
ImportError: No module named '_tkinter', please install the python3-tk package
>>> quit()
```

whereas python3-tk is already installed :

```
silvock@silvock-TM1701 ~ $ sudo apt-get install python3-tk

Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
python3-tk est déjà la version la plus récente (3.6.5-3~16.04.york0.2).
0 mis à jour, 0 nouvellement installés, 0 à enlever et 0 non mis à jour.
```

I would like to tkinter work with python3.5.

I try in vain

```
silvock@silvock-TM1701 ~ $ sudo apt-get install python3.5-tk
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
Le paquet python3.5-tk est un paquet virtuel fourni par :
  python3-tk 3.5.1-1 [Pas de version candidate]

E: Le paquet « python3.5-tk » n'a pas de version susceptible d'être installée
sions de Python.
```

Comment: Are you using a different PPA for python 3.6? Your tkinter is for version 3.6.5. I have the same problem on my Linux Mint 18.1. I sue a PPA that doesn't maintain the discipline of using "3.6" in its name. Its `python3-tk` should be `python3.6-tk`. I've never dug into how the one for 3.5 could be installed. I think I'll gide it a try.

Comment: Running `apt-cache policy python3-tk` I see I have 2 versions: 3.6.5 from the PPA `http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages` and 3.5.1 from my mirror of `ubuntu xenial`.

Comment: `silvock@silvock-TM1701 ~ $ apt-cache policy python3-tk
python3-tk:
  Installé : 3.6.5-3~16.04.york0.2
  Candidat : 3.6.5-3~16.04.york0.2
 Table de version :
 *** 3.6.5-3~16.04.york0.2 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.5.1-1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages`

Comment: Same problem. My planned solution is to wait for Linux Mint 19 which should be out any day now... It is python 3.6 based so no need for the extra PPA. Its just my home notepad so no big deal.

Comment: I think that the solution is to find a different PPA that names things 3.6 specifically. This one maybe: https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+build/14508386. Remove the existing PPA, purge packages from that PPA, reinstall python3-tk plus any other ones that disappeared (now you'll get the 3.5 versions), add the new PPA and install `python3.6-tk`. I haven't tried it though...

Comment: Could be the issue ? : No `_tkinter.so` in python3-tk : https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/python3-tk/filelist .... Only in python-tk https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/amd64/python-tk/filelist

Comment: I think, I will wait for linux mint 19 too